# Call functions with @() in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to figure out what is the purpose of @(t) in the following code snippet:

```
 [theta] = ...
     fmincg (@(t)(lrCostFunction(t, X, (y == c), lambda)), ...
             initial_theta, options);
```

lrCostFunction:

```
function [J, grad] = lrCostFunction(theta, X, y, lambda)
%LRCOSTFUNCTION Compute cost and gradient for logistic regression with 
%regularization
%   J = LRCOSTFUNCTION(theta, X, y, lambda) computes the cost of using
%   theta as the parameter for regularized logistic regression and the
%   gradient of the cost w.r.t. to the parameters.
```

and options:

```
options = optimset('GradObj', 'on', 'MaxIter', 50);
```

I'd appreciate some explanation. Thanks in advance

Comment: That's an anonymous function. The single variable theta is optimized in lrCostFunction. http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me answer your question focusing on [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) itself.

The following function, defined in a separate .m file

```
function y = foo(x, a, b)
    y = x^(a-b);
end
```

is equivalent to defining an anonymous function in the main script

```
bar = @(x, a, b) x^(a-b);
```

When your main script calls function `foo(5, 1, 2)`, Matlab searches in working directory, then reads and executes code within file `foo.m`. Contrarily, when you run a line `bar(5, 1, 2)`, Matlab calls a ["function handle"](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/function-handles.html) and treat it as a function (though its power is limited by a single line of code - you can't perform things like `switch` or `for` easily).

Sometimes we need to wrap some function into an easier-to-use one. Consider a case where we want to evaluate `foo` 1000 times, but only input `x` changes, while `a` and `b` remains same. It's of course OK to write `foo(x, 1, 2)` in the `for` loop, but you can also wrap the function before going into the loop.

```
a = 1;
b = 2;
foobar = @(x) foo(x, a, b);
```

When you call `foobar(5)`, Matlab first invokes the function handle `foobar`, taking `5` as its only input. That function handle has one instruction: call another function (or function handle, if you define it as so) named `foo`. The arguments of `foo` are: `x`, which is defined when user calls `foobar(x)`; `a` and `b`, which have been defined in the first place BEFORE the function handle definition code is executed.

In your case, `fmincg` only accepts, as its first argument, a function that only has one input argument. But `lrCostFunction` takes four. `fmincg` doesn't know how to treat `x`, `y`, or `lambda` (I don't either). So it's your job to wrap the cost function into the form that a general optimizer can understand. That also requires you assign `x`, `y`, `c` and `lambda` in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**What is it.**

@(t) creates a function with argument `t` that calls your `costFunction(t,X,y)` so if you write

```
fmincg (@(t)(lrCostFunction(t, X, (y == c), lambda)), ...
             initial_theta, options);
```

it will call your function `lrCostFunction` and pass the values

**Why we need it**

It allows us to use the built in optimization function provided by Octave (*because MATLAB doesn't have fminc function AFAIK*).  So it takes your costFunction and Optimise it using the settings that you provide.

**Optimization  Settings**

`optimset('GradObj', 'on', 'MaxIter', 50);` allows you to set the Optimization settings that are required for minimization problem as mentioned above.

All information is from Andrew NG classes. I hope it helps..

Correct me if I am wrong.